# Another Six-words (------||||||)

Tags: word, wordplay, crosswords, word-square

> People call me crazy. I think perhaps I am
>   I just seek justice and there is no other way
>   I don't want to create chaos: quite the opposite.
>   It is a voice chanting in my head. (Or do others hear it too?)
>   It is my primary purpose now behind all things I do.
>   It is what gets me up in the morning. My one grain of hope.

This proving tougher than I expected so another 6 clues for the same six words:

> See that I am a man just a bit mixed up.
>   My anger is vindicated (somewhat).
>   Kept orderly and pure
>   In simple harmony
>   This generous day nearly complete, my plan
>   Grows across the world. See that it is real!

And in case anyone doesn't understand, expressed as a crossword the words for each down is the same as each across:

[image: a wordsquare]

Answer (score 7, accepted):

> $$\matrix{M&A&N&I&A&C\\A&V&E&N&G&E\\N&E&A&T&E&R\\I&N&T&O&N&E\\A&G&E&N&D&A\\C&E&R&E&A&L}$$

Comment: Well done Jared

Comment: Nice one Jared and @Avon!

Comment: Thank you @rand. I was hoping you'd get it. I'm sorry it didn't quite click for you.

Answer (score 1):

*People call me crazy. I think perhaps I am*

> INSANE.

*I just seek justice and there is no other way*

> Not sure yet...

*I don't want to create chaos: quite the opposite.*

> SYSTEM.

*It is a voice chanting in my head. (Or do others hear it too?)*

> Not sure yet...

*It is my primary purpose now behind all things I do.*

> I thought MOTIVE, but it doesn't fit with what I've got so far.

*It is what gets me up in the morning. My one grain of hope.*

> Not sure yet...

Comment: I don't want to give clues on this: I don't think it needs it. Good thinking on the three answers. They're perfectly good answers if they were standalone. But don't interpret that as me saying they are correct though. They may or may not be.

Comment: Only word I've found that goes n_y (third clue) is noyade, and that makes the fifth word nda and the last eem. I think you've got to have at least one, but it seems probably only one.

Comment: I expect the third and fourth are going to be the hardest to get. I suggest leave them to last. Probably the 6th is the best to start with.

Comment: @Avon I thought of "motive" or something about "drive" for the 6th, but can't think of any words ending in V...

Comment: @rand no neither can I :) It is neither of those words. Think more... political

Comment: @rand Ah sorry. This is for 5. I don't mean a particular message or even just politicians. What do those involved in politics (politicians, journalists, lobbyists, etc) generally have (hidden)? 6 is much more pedestrian. Try to put the 'story' aside for that.

Comment: @Avon Well, their "primary purpose behind all things they do" is surely MONEY, but that's only 5 letters too. Edit: oh, maybe PROFIT?

Comment: @rand Certainly true for most. I'm not sure absolutely all. Money is just a means to selection of ends anyway. Another set of clues coming up.

Comment: @Avon I thought of POWER (but only 5 letters) and CHANGE...