# Yet Another Six-words (------||||||)

Tags: word-square, cryptic-clues

Following [@Prem](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/users/10940/prem)'s [four-word puzzle](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/questions/15339/four-words), I thought I'd have a go.  (There have been a few other similar things, e.g. [here](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/questions/15407/another-six-words), [here](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/questions/15347/six-words-six-words)).

There are 6 words each with 6 letters.  If written in 6 rows (to make a 6x6 square) the same words read down as well as across.  Below are 6 cryptic clues to the 6 words.

**The clues have been mixed up to increase the challenge a little**

> Aristocrat eats honey. Gatherer thwarts unfairly.
>   Equip to ban eel stew.
>   Not exactly round at the trail's end.
>   Guides in haste erstwhile bulls.
>   Tea tears apart fashions.
>   Drearier droning undoes lovely lilts, even right at the beginning.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> `TRENDS` 
>   `RUNOUT` 
>   `ENABLE` 
>   `NOBBLE` 
>   `DULLER` 
>   `STEERS`

Aristocrat eats honey. Gatherer thwarts unfairly.

> Noble holding 'b' (honey gather). To **nobble** is to thwart unfairly.

Equip to ban eel stew.

> Anagram of 'ban eel': **enable**

Not exactly round at the trail's end.

> To end is to **run out**. Runout is also when a tool is slightly off centre.

Guides in haste erstwhile bulls.

> ha**ste ers**twhile. To guide is to steer, and a bull is a steer.

Tea tears apart fashions.

> 'T' + rends: **Trends**

Drearier droning undoes lovely lilts, even right at the beginning.

> **d**roning **u**ndoes **l**ovely **l**ilts, **e**ven **r**ight:

Comment: Runout is also when a tool is slightly off centre

Comment: Great job! Hope you enjoyed it

Comment: I added the explanation for runout, thanks for that and for an interesting puzzle.